# Bootstrap 4.2 scripts not loading/working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following head on my html file, but it seems like there's something wrong, because I'm trying to use scrollspy and navbar collapse and neither of them will work

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Nova Bookings</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- Univia Pro Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/wqq0dwp.css">
    <!-- Franklin Gothic -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/wqq0dwp.css">

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

This is my body:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-custom fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" date-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                ....
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I don't see anything wrong here... Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] and clearly tell us what the issue is?

Comment: Why are you using the slim version of jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js load the full version. Animation effects like jQuery.easing, jQuery.Animation, jQuery.speed are removed from the slim version.

Comment: Do you have errors in console?

Comment: @KamilNaja the only error i get is this: "Not allowed to load local resource" which i guess is unrelated...

Comment: @HenslerSoftware i'm using the slim version because i just copied and pasted the links from the bootstrap website. but i just tried the full version after reading your comment and it's still not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap should be loading/working properly with the code you posted above. The problem is that you wrote `date-toggle` instead of `data-toggle`. Test the code below to make sure it works:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-custom fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No problem! Cheers!